# loop only through selected files

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Do you know how to loop only through selected files in a folder with VBA?
I managed to do the code for looping through all the files. However, I'd like to shorten the time of processing to make it open only the files which I specify in the code.

```
Sub CopyDataFromCSTR()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim i As Long



  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


myPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"


  myExtension = "*.xlsx*"

  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'attempt to set a criteria for the files to open - however the loop ends at first attempt
  Do While InStr(myFile, "Trans") <> 0

      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'do something to the opened file



      wb.Close SaveChanges:=False


      DoEvents


      myFile = Dir
  Loop

  Set wb = Nothing

  MsgBox ("Done!")

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True




End Sub
```

Comment: Remove this condition `Do While InStr(myFile, "Trans") <> 0` with `Do while  myFile <> ""` you can check the conditions based on names inside the do while loop and skip if it doesn't qualifies.

Comment: Threre is one thing I did not mention in my question. The file names contain specific wording among other characters. For example, I would like to open only files that among other characters in file's name has specific string; "trans". The file name could look like this: 20170311sdfsdfTransfasdfasd.xlsx or 20170310fasdfTransasdfaw.xlsx. Is there any way to incorporate INSTR function in recognizing the files we want to select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is modified from my favourite treewalking routine. I've omitted the recursive call so it just searches the specified folder. Normally I set References, but here I've late bound the scripting objects.

For this POC we just open the file, debug.print the name and close it

```
Sub ScanFldr(sFld As String, sPat As String)
    Dim fso As Object, fld As Object, fil As Object
    Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder(sFld)
    If Right(sFld, 1) <> "\" Then sFld = sFld & "\"

    For Each fil In fld.Files
        If fil.Name Like sPat And Not (fil.Name Like "~$*" or fil.Name = thisWorkBook.Name) Then
            Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFld & fil.Name, ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False)
            Debug.Print "Opened " & fil.Name
            wkb.Close savechanges:=False
        End If
        DoEvents
    Next
    Set wkb = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

call as e.g.

```
ScanFldr thisworkbook.path, "*.xlsx*"
```

Note that to use thisworkbook.path then you need to save the workbook containing the code before running the macro.

Answer (score 1):

Where you have * before the . in Replace myExtension = "*.xlsx*", replace the * with a file mask for the file.
For example:
"FilesLikeThis.xlsx*"
You may want to rename the variable to FileMask or something more appropriate.

For example, for files starting with the word hello only:

```
    myFileName = "hello*"
    myExtension = "xlsx*"
    myFile = Dir(myPath & myFileName & "." & myExtension)
```

Don't forget to add a Dim for the new variable.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, I would like to open only files that among other characters in file's name has specific string; "trans". The file name could look like this: 20170311sdfsdfTransfasdfasd.xlsx or 20170310fasdfTransasdfaw.xlsx. Is there any way to incorporate INSTR function in recognizing the files we want to select?

```
Sub CopyDataFromCSTR()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim i As Long

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

myPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"

  myExtension = "*.xls*"
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)


  Do While myFile <> 0
```

> ```
>  if instr(myFile, "trans") > 0 then    'Check condition inside the loop instead of ending the do-while loop abruptly
> ```

```
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
    'do something to the opened file
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
      DoEvents
```

> ```
>    End if
> ```

```
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

  Set wb = Nothing    
  MsgBox ("Done!")

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```